# Добавление custom view

Tags: java, android, view

Есть две идентичные View'шки, в них методы `onDraw()` и `OnTouchEvent()`. 
По отдельности каждая отлично отрабатывает. Но при добавление их в `Activity` работает только та, которая была добавлена последней.

Как исправить?

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    RelativeLayout rlPlay;


    int wrapContent = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

        rlPlay=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlPlay);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent,wrapContent);

        Protect1 pt1=new Protect1(this);
        Protect2 pt2=new Protect2(this);

        rlPlay.addView(pt1,lParams);
        rlPlay.addView(pt2,lParams);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

По моему ваши View ложатся друг на друга, поэтому ощущение, что срабатывает только один. Попробуйте задать им разные координаты.

Как примерно в следующем коде, только свой View укажите. [Код отсюда](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/relativelayout.php)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   EditText editText = new EditText(this);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
   // use same id as defined when adding the button
   params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 1001);
   editText.setLayoutParams(params);
   editText.setHint("Введите имя кота....");

   Button button = new Button(this);
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
   button.setLayoutParams(params2);
   button.setText("Нажми нежно!");
   // give the button an id that we know
   button.setId(1001);
   RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
   layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   layout.addView(editText);
   layout.addView(button);
   setContentView(layout);
}
```

Comment: Дело в том, что да, перекрывает, но при swipe, объект должен изменить координаты, а это он делает только в области отведённого ему Layout'a. То есть область передвижения view'шки должна быть на всё игровое поле, на котором те же самые view'шки стоят. И последняя добавленная view перекрывает предыдущие.